# Endeca cluster setup

Tags: atg, endeca

I have configured an (Endeca Application Controller) EAC application on Multiple  servers. I have two machines A and B with the following configurations.

Machine A: Oracle Endeca MDEX Engine, Oracle Endeca Platform Services (Endeca Application Controller Server and agent), Oracle Endeca Tools and Frameworks, Content Administration System (CAS).

Machine B: Oracle Endeca MDEX Engine, Oracle Endeca Platform Services (EAC agent only instance).

I have a [Dgraph Cluster](http://mandarshinde.com/oracle-endeca-cluster-setup/) (1 MDEX  and 1 Dgraph on each host)

I need to know is there any need of setting up an [Endeca Server Cluster](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29805_01/server.230/es_admin/src/cadm_clustering_root.html)
when my website is up and Running? I have an ATG-Endeca Integration Environment and my indexed data is quite large. 
Also I need to know is there any criteria for determining the number of servers, server topology, and the load balancer topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a cluster if you are sharing disk between the mdex instances.

In terms of the number of servers and layout, it depends most on the number of queries that are expected and amount of effort (computation time) it takes to run the queries.

I am sure that the Oracle Endeca sales / support staff that set you up should be able to provide some baselines for these numbers.

Comment: What do you mean with 'sharing disk between mdex instances'?